# Select2 get option value that triggers selecting/unselecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

https://select2.github.io/options.html#what-events-will-select2-trigger

The documentation, says that `select2:selecting` and `select2:unselecting` can be prevented. 
I want to prevent the event conditionally depending on the value being selected/unselected.

```
$('select').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
  // what value is currently being selected?
  // $(this).val() does not yet have it and I should set it conditionally
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All info about selected option contains `e` variable of your function so you can get it like this:

```
$('select').select2().on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
  console.log(e.params.args.data.id); //value of selected  option
  console.log(e.params.args.data.text); // text of selected option
});
```

[Check this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/k6vgy216/).